# Justify thumbs horizontally

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Check this code below

HTML:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 var $this=$('<a href="#"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/150x150/444/fff" alt=""/></a>');
  for (var i=0;i<=9;i++){
   $("#thumbs").append($this.clone());
  }
});
```

```css
#thumbs {   
    width: 100%;
    margin-top:90px;
     text-align: justify;
    -ms-text-justify: distribute-all-lines;
    text-justify: distribute-all-lines;
}
#thumbs a {
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    zoom: 1;
}
.stretch {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 0;
    line-height: 0
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="thumbs">
    <a href="#"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/150x150/444/fff" alt=""/></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/150x150/444/fff" alt=""/></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/150x150/444/fff" alt=""/></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/150x150/444/fff" alt=""/></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/150x150/444/fff" alt=""/></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/150x150/444/fff" alt=""/></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/150x150/444/fff" alt=""/></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/150x150/444/fff" alt=""/></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/150x150/444/fff" alt=""/></a>
</div>
```

Anchor tags gets justified when added directly in html page but not gets justified when added from javascript.

Any suggestions? Don't forget to check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JTcGZ/1596/)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't support below IE10, you can use `flexbox`. It will definitely work. Check https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ for more information.

```
#thumbs{ display:flex; justify-content: space-between; }
```

Comment: I have other alternates. just trying to find why this is not working?